# Exclude directory with tar

Tags: command-line, tar

```
find /home/karl/dev/beer/ -printf "%P\n" | tar --exclude='./.git' -czf beer.tgz --no-recursion -C /home/karl/dev/beer/ -T -
```

The command still includes the .git directory.

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @Zanna Nope! Not yet!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude the directory in find like this:

```
find /home/karl/dev/beer -path .git -prune -printf "%P\n" | tar -czf beer.tar.gz --no-recursion  -T -
```

You can check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) discussion.

Comment: No files are added now :(

Comment: Try to remove also the printf command in find. I am not sure you need it

Answer (score 0):

from `man find`:

```
 -printf
 ....
 %P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found 
        removed.
```

So you are excluding a directory that doesn't exist in your output. If you look at the output of your `find` command before you pipe it (generally a good idea), you will see it has no leading `./`. So, you should use `--exclude='.git'` not `./.git`

But rather than using `find` for this, you might want to use `globstar` to make globbing recursive:

```
shopt -s globstar
tar --exclude='.git' -czvf beer.tar.gz /home/karl/dev/beer/**
```